# Intent to launch call history and contacts for a particular person?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, android-activity

I have a contact's phone number and name. With this information, how can I launch the contact:

1. call history details activity
2. edit contacts activity

I'm able to launch just the starting activity of call history and contacts. Instead I want to directly navigate into a person's record. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you got the answer? I too looking for such intent.

Comment: not yet... Still looking for the answer...

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. Please take a look.

```
   contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);

   int phoneCallLogID = new Random().nextInt();
   Cursor callLogLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,contactNumber),null, null, null, null);
       while(callLogLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
           phoneCallLogID = callLogLookupCursor.getInt(callLogLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls._ID));

           }
       callLogLookupCursor.close();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(phoneCallLogID));



   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(uri);
   startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When answering, please try to provide details including an explanation as to what your code does and *why* it should work. This helps the OP and future visitors to learn what the problem is/was.